# Memory Difference between actual from task manager and Manual Calculated in c++ singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, centos

I run a c++ singly linked list append operation for 100000000 nodes the node take random number each time between 0-10 , In centos 64bit, it takes size of 16 for each node so it will be 1600000000 but according to task manager shown as 30.53mb for each node.

The node Class contains int data and node* next, thats it.

My Questions:

1.Why this different?

2.Is any specific way to obtain the equal size?

Comment: Sounds strange. First thing you have to get right is proper measurement of the memory resources.

Comment: "according to task manager shown as 30.53mb for each node" - What does that mean? Are you really seeing 3053000000000000 bytes being used? Where did you buy your computer?

Answer (score 2):

All "lumps" of memory being allocated have an overhead, which is typically 16-64 bytes per allocation.

If you make two memory allocations in a row, how far apart are those. E.g.

```
char *a = new char;
char *b = new char;

std::cout << b-a << std::endl;

delete a;
delete b;
```

(And yes, before someone else points it out: Technically this code is undefined behaviour. But on a x86-64 machine, the memory is a flat memory model, so subtracting one pointer from another should give you the distance between the two objects. One of the reasons that the standard doesn't allow for the "difference between memory of different allocations" is that it's possible that the architecture uses segmented memory a'la 16-bit OS/2, where each allocation has it's own segment, and a segment has it's own base-address, where the base-address is not known by the user-mode application, so it's impossible to use this sort of trick)

Comment: Ya it provides 32 ... can u say any exact way to solve my problem

Comment: So that answers your question, doesn't it? You have a 32-byte per item "overhead". So your memory usage matches the expected memory usage if we use 32 instead of 16. Or did you actually mean 30.53MB for each node, meaning your memory usage is in the terabytes range?

Of course, you can improve on the memory usage by allocating in larger blocks, but it also makes the code more complex. Not using a linked list would of course be another option...

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the nodes for your list? `new`? `malloc`?
All those memory allocation functions consume some extra space to allow the memory management (e.g. deallocation and reclaiming the memory). This overhead is most apparent when you allocate a lot of small pieces of memory.

I think that is the reason of this memory overhead you are seeing.

You can try the following:

- If you only allocate small pieces of the same size - try using a fixed array (or just allocated-once array) and then use pointers to the array elements as `next` member of your list node.
- You can also try alternative implementations of `malloc`, for example [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)

Comment: i used new for memory allocation

Comment: Actually adding the size information (of malloc) gives: 3000 / 24 = 125